# QField doesnt recognize project data

Tags: qgis, export, qfield

I'm using QGIS 3.22.8 LTR, and exporting data via "cable export", creating a QField project (qgz) then sending it to a zip folder, transferring to the mobile device and unpacking it directly in QGField.

This worked for one project, showing all the shape layers and the cropped basemap. Now if I do the same process again, QField seems not to find the project file, it opens the project only showing red shapes without any attributes and it does`t recognize it as project but just as a file.

In the zip folder there is definitely a qgs file, the shapefiles get copied and the cropped basemap gets exported as a geopackage layer.

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you read that: https://www.opengis.ch/de/2022/03/05/qfield-users-sit-down-we-need-to-talk-about-storage-access-on-android%EF%BF%BC/ - saying "TLDR: Since November 2021, Google has enforced new storage access limitations for apps published on its Play store which prohibits direct storage access on Android 11 and above forcing QField to adapt and rely on importing projects and datasets to access those."